# Measures on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}_p)$?

Tags: measure-theory, projective-space

Is there a natural measure on the above spaces? Ideally, I would like a measure that is invariant under automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^1$.